# Node.js spawn, listen to multiple close events

Tags: node.js, spawn

I have multiple `spawns` running together and I want to listen to the `close` command, but for all of them.  So when ALL child processes trigger `close`.  Does anyone know if there's a native way to handle this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a little confusing. Are you wanting the close events to run the same code? Just make a function that all the close events call. Or are you looking to do something different?

Comment: I'm also confused about what you mean by when all the child processes close. Are you killing them all at the exact same time? Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @JoshuaAllen That's what I ended up doing - I wasn't sure if there was a way to somehow chain the close's of multiple processes, I think I was just over complicating it in my thinking.